# Break down ternary operator into if statment?

Tags: php, conditional-operator

I have code code like this:

`$get_options = isset($options['big_heading']) ? ($options['big_heading']) : '' ;` but i am having hard time reading this as ternary operator so how can I break it down into an if statment? Sorry for my noobish question...
Thank you!!

Comment: Hmm, using ternary operator is fine and better for readability than if/else statement. Well, that's subjective.

Comment: what rubbish happening here, you think that this is the right space to ask like this question. :(

Comment: Well Neeraj Singh not everybody know PHP like you do so some of us are still learning this stuff...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code equals:

```
if(isset( $options['big_heading'])){
    $get_options = $options['big_heading'];
} else {
    $get_options = '';
}
```

Syntax of this is always like: `$foo = (condition) ? if_its_true : if_its_not_true ;`

Answer (score 1):

This is same as

```
$get_options = isset( $options['big_heading']) ? ($options['big_heading']) : '' ;
```

this

```
if(isset( $options['big_heading'])) {
    $get_options = $options['big_heading'];
} else {
    $get_options = '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset( $options['big_heading'])) {
  $get_options = $options['big_heading'];
} else {
  $get_options = '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$get_options = "";

if(isset( $options['big_heading']))
{
   $get_options = $options['big_heading']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$get_options =  '' ;
if (isset( $options['big_heading'])) {
 $get_options = $options['big_heading'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go...

```
if (isset($options['big_heading'])){
    $get_options = $options['big_heading'];
else{
    $get_options = '';
}
```